# Is it possible to get a volatile field using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

```
Class<? extends Class> clazz = MyClass.class.getClass();
try {
    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("mInstance");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    looper = (Looper) field.get(this);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The field is declared like this:
`private volatile Object mInstance;`

I'm receiving a `NoSuchFieldException`.

Comment: `MyClass.class.getClass()` will return an object of `Class<Class>` while you need `Class<MyClass>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
Class<? extends Class> clazz = MyClass.class.getClass();
```

should be

```
Class<?> clazz = MyClass.class; // or Class<MyClass>
```

That is known as a *class literal*. The expression results in a `Class` object for the given type. Calling `getClass()` on a `Class` instance will return the `Class` instance for `Class`, not for `MyClass`.

(All this assumes that the field `mInstance` is declared in `MyClass`.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `MyClass.class`

Simple test would be run following code:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A.class.getClass());
        System.out.println(A.class);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
class java.lang.Class
class A
```

Also see [Retrieving Class Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html)

Cheers !!